# Cannot read the file /sys/kernel/debug/irq_domain_mapping although with "read" permission

Tags: c, linux, permission-denied

I am facing this very strange issue.
I wrote a C-function to read value from path "/sys/kernel/debug/irq_domain_mapping" on my linux runing board. Although the that file has "read" permission for all user/group/other, but my function was still not able to read its content.

Would you please help me with some possibilities for this issue. It 's quite strange and this is the first time I got it.

Thanks in advance.

```
/* Define the file path */
#define HAL_IRQ_DOMAIN_MAP_FILE     "/sys/kernel/debug/irq_domain_mapping" /**< irq map file location and mapping */

/* Open the file with permission read */
FILE *fp = NULL;
fp = fopen(HAL_IRQ_DOMAIN_MAP_FILE, "r");
if (fp == NULL) {
    tpLOG_osErr("fopen", HAL_IRQ_DOMAIN_MAP_FILE);
    return errno;
}
```

**But can not read the file**

```
Oct 3 01:12:59    fopen /sys/kernel/debug/irq_domain_mapping failed: 'Permission denied'
```

**Although the file has read permission for all**

```
[root@]#ls -la /sys/kernel/debug/irq_domain_mapping
ls -la /sys/kernel/debug/irq_domain_mapping
**-r--r--r--    1 root     root             0 Jan  1  1970 /sys/kernel/debug/irq_domain_mapping**
```

Comment: The `/sys/kernel/debug` directory is typically executable and readable only by `root`.

Comment: Hi kaylum, Would you help give more details, my function is actually reading the file in /sys/kernel/debug, so why it cannot read ????

Comment: In Linux you can't access a file if the directory it is in is not executable. The "permission denied" that you are getting is actually for the directory and not the file. Try `sudo chmod o+rx /sys/kernel/debug`. But note that the permissions will revert on reboot.

Comment: I got your point. your comment makes sense to me. But I am afraid that it is not the case. Because when my board boots up, it runs this sort of script to set appropriate permission :  chmod 755 /sys/kernel/debug ; chgrp power /sys/kernel/debug/irq_domain_mapping

Comment: Have you debugged it on the command line? That is, can you access that file as a non-root user from the command line?

Comment: Hi kaylum, thanks for your recommending, it 's good